# How to clear Canvas before drop new image on HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Dear I have small html5 canvas project that getting example from codepen to drag&drop image using html5 canvas. Example work fine, but I have problem once  new image placed, then all of them are overlap in image area. Below is javascript code

```
<script>
  var imgW;
  function drawImg() {
    var x = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var canvax = x.getContext('2d'); 
    var imgElement = document.getElementById('imgCanvas');
    var imgObj = new Image();
    imgObj.src = imgElement.src;
    var imgW = imgObj.width;
    var imgH = imgObj.height;
    var imgX = canvax.canvas.width * .5 - imgW * .5;
    var imgY = canvax.canvas.height * .5 - imgH * .5;
    imgObj.onload = function () {
      canvax.clearRect(imgX, imgY, imgW, imgH); 
      canvax.drawImage(imgObj, imgX, imgY, imgW, imgH); 
    };
  }

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.listImg li').draggable({ containment: 'document', opacity: 0.60, revert: false, helper: 'clone',
      start: function () {
        $('.infoDrag').text('Start Drag');
      },
      drag: function () {
        $('.infoDrag').text('on Dragging');
      },
      stop: function () {
        $('.infoDrag').text('Stop Dragging');
      } });

    $('#myCanvas').droppable({ hoverClass: 'dashborder', tolerance: 'pointer',
      drop: function (ev, ui) {
        var droppedItem = $(ui.draggable).clone();
        var canvasImg = $(this).find('img');
        var newSrc = droppedItem.find('img').attr('src');
        canvasImg.attr("src", newSrc);
        drawImg();
      } });

    $('#myCanvas').dblclick(function () {
      $('#myCanvas').draggable();
    });
  });
</script>
```

My need is to clear image before place new image. I may need to use clearRect method. But since tried several but not work. Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the size and position of a (newly) loaded image as the bounding rectangle you feed to **clearRect()** use the size of the canvas itself.

Simply change

```
canvax.clearRect(imgX, imgY, imgW, imgH);
```

to

```
canvax.clearRect(0, 0, x.width, x.height);
```